# Having issues whith Exsist

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help with this Question.
.  Write a script that has one line out output that says either “March sales are greater than April sales” or “April sales are greater than March sales”, depending on which is true.  You will need to sum up the sales (consider it the litem price minus the discount for those sales in that month) and then use an if/else. So i figured to do it like this

```
Use MyGuitarShop;

DECLARE @AprilSales MONEY;
DECLARE @MarchSales MONEY;

SET @AprilSales = (SELECT MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) as SalesMonth,
         SUM(OrderItems.ItemPrice-OrderItems.DiscountAmount) AS    TotalSales
FROM Orders,OrderItems
 WHERE MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) = 4
GROUP BY MONTH(Orders.OrderDate));

SET @MarchSales = (SELECT MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) as SalesMonth,
     SUM(OrderItems.ItemPrice-OrderItems.DiscountAmount) AS TotalSales
FROM Orders,OrderItems
WHERE MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) = 3
GROUP BY MONTH(Orders.OrderDate));

SELECT @AprilSales, @MarchSales
FROM Orders, OrderItems 
 IF @AprilSales > @MarchSales 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'April sales are greater than March sales.'
END;
 ELSE --@MarchSales > @AprilSales
    PRINT 'March sales are greater than April sales.';
```

But i Get this error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: remove `MONTH(Orders.OrderDate) as SalesMonth` from you `SELECT` statements

Comment: @Ed Harper. I did this but it returns columns an not my print statements. I need it to compare the two values an return on of the print statements depending on which month had the greater sales.

Comment: @DanielStallard that is because you are doing a select before the IF which you don't need. But you have another problem too when calculating the sales: you are not joining Orders and OrderItems, this will produce a cartesian product and your sales will add up to an incorrectly huge number

Comment: Yea i actually caught on to that thanks for the help guys. all runs smooth.@Ed Harper And @Jayvee